# Python recursive folder read

Tags: python, scripting, file-io

I have a C++/Obj-C background and I am just discovering Python (been writing it for about an hour).
I am writing a script to recursively read the contents of text files in a folder structure.

The problem I have is the code I have written will only work for one folder deep. I can see why in the code (see `#hardcoded path`), I just don't know how I can move forward with Python since my experience with it is only brand new.

**Python Code:**

```
import os
import sys

rootdir = sys.argv[1]

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):

    for folder in subFolders:
        outfileName = rootdir + "/" + folder + "/py-outfile.txt" # hardcoded path
        folderOut = open( outfileName, 'w' )
        print "outfileName is " + outfileName

        for file in files:
            filePath = rootdir + '/' + file
            f = open( filePath, 'r' )
            toWrite = f.read()
            print "Writing '" + toWrite + "' to" + filePath
            folderOut.write( toWrite )
            f.close()

        folderOut.close()
```

Answer (score 467, accepted):

Make sure you understand the three return values of `os.walk`:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
```

has the following meaning:

- `root`: Current path which is "walked through"
- `subdirs`: Files in `root` of type directory
- `files`: Files in `root` (not in `subdirs`) of type other than directory

And please use `os.path.join` instead of concatenating with a slash! Your problem is `filePath = rootdir + '/' + file` - you must concatenate the currently "walked" folder instead of the topmost folder. So that must be `filePath = os.path.join(root, file)`. BTW "file" is a builtin, so you don't normally use it as variable name.

Another problem are your loops, which should be like this, for example:

```
import os
import sys

walk_dir = sys.argv[1]

print('walk_dir = ' + walk_dir)

# If your current working directory may change during script execution, it's recommended to
# immediately convert program arguments to an absolute path. Then the variable root below will
# be an absolute path as well. Example:
# walk_dir = os.path.abspath(walk_dir)
print('walk_dir (absolute) = ' + os.path.abspath(walk_dir))

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(walk_dir):
    print('--\nroot = ' + root)
    list_file_path = os.path.join(root, 'my-directory-list.txt')
    print('list_file_path = ' + list_file_path)

    with open(list_file_path, 'wb') as list_file:
        for subdir in subdirs:
            print('\t- subdirectory ' + subdir)

        for filename in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            print('\t- file %s (full path: %s)' % (filename, file_path))

            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                f_content = f.read()
                list_file.write(('The file %s contains:\n' % filename).encode('utf-8'))
                list_file.write(f_content)
                list_file.write(b'\n')
```

If you didn't know, the `with` statement for files is a shorthand:

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as f:
    dosomething()

# is effectively the same as

f = open('filename', 'rb')
try:
    dosomething()
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Superb, lots of prints to understand what's going on and it works perfectly. Thanks! +1

Comment: Heads up to anyone as dumb/oblivious as me... this code sample writes a txt file to each directory. Glad I tested it in a version controlled folder, though everything I need to write a cleanup script is here too :)

Comment: that second (longest) code snippet worked very well, saved me a lot of boring work

Comment: Since speed if obviously the most important aspect, `os.walk` is not bad, though I came up with an even faster way via `os.scandir`. All `glob` solutions are a lot slower than `walk` & `scandir`. My function, as well as a complete speed analysis, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803793/2441026

Comment: This is a great SO answer, not only drilling into the issue but stuff like this 
"BTW "file" is a builtin, so you don't normally use it as variable name." 
is golden for someone new to a language

Answer (score 275):

If you are using Python 3.5 or above, you can get this done in 1 line.

```
import glob

# root_dir needs a trailing slash (i.e. /root/dir/)
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.txt', recursive=True):
     print(filename)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

> If recursive is true, the pattern '**' will match any files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.

If you want every file, you can use

```
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/**', recursive=True):
     print(filename)
```

Comment: TypeError: iglob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

Comment: As mentioned in the beginning, it is only for Python 3.5+

Comment: root_dir must have a trailing slash (otherwise you get something like 'folder**/*' instead of 'folder/**/*' as the first argument). You can use os.path.join(root_dir, '**/*'), but I don't know if it's acceptable to use os.path.join with wildcard paths (it works for my application though).

Comment: @ChillarAnand Can you please add a comment to the code in this answer that `root_dir` needs a trailing slash?  This will save people time (or at least it would have saved me time).  Thanks.

Comment: If I ran this as in the answer it didn't work recursively. To make this work recursively I had to change it to: `glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/**', recursive=True)`. I'm working in Python 3.8.2

Comment: Like mikey said, the command didn't work for me on Python 3.8; it did not find any files. Using `**/**` instead of `**/*` solved it and shows all files. But I'm still unsure how to filter for certain file types. Eg, neither `**/*.csv` nor `**/**.csv` showed any of the CSV files that I have in child folders.

Comment: Be aware that glob.glob does not match dotfiles. You may use pathlib.glob instead

Answer (score 45):

Agree with Dave Webb, `os.walk` will yield an item for each directory in the tree. Fact is, you just don't have to care about `subFolders`.

Code like this should work:

```
import os
import sys

rootdir = sys.argv[1]

for folder, subs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'python-outfile.txt'), 'w') as dest:
        for filename in files:
            with open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'r') as src:
                dest.write(src.read())
```

Comment: Nice one. This works as well. I do however prefer AndiDog's version even though its longer because it's clearer to understand as a beginner to Python. +1

Answer (score 41):

**TL;DR:** These are equivalents to `find -type f`, to go over all files in all folders below and including the current one:

```
folder = '.'

import os
for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(currentpath, file))
## or:
import glob
for pathstr in glob.iglob(glob.escape(folder) + '/**/*', recursive=True):
    print(pathstr)
```

Comparing the two methods:

- `os.walk` is about 3× faster
- `os.walk` used slightly more memory in my test because the `files` array held 82k entries whereas `glob` returns an iterator and streams the results. The piecemeal handling of each result (more calls and less buffering going on) likely explains the speed difference

  - If you forget the `i` in `glob.iglob()`, it will return a list rather than an iterator and potentially use a *lot* more memory
- `os.walk` will not silently give incomplete results or unexpectedly interpret a *name* as a matching pattern
- `glob` doesn't show empty directories
- `glob` needs to escape directory and file names using `glob.escape(name)` because they can contain special characters
- `glob` excludes directories and files starting with a dot (e.g., `~/.bashrc` or `~/.vim`) and `include_hidden` does not solve that (it includes hidden *folders* only; you need to specify a second pattern for dotfiles)
- `glob` doesn't tell you what is a file and what a directory
- `glob` walks into symlinks and may lead to you enumerating a lot of files in completely different places (which may be what you want; in that case, `os.walk` has `followlinks=True` as an option)
- `os.walk` lets you modify which paths to walk down by modifying the folders array while it's running, though personally this feels a bit messy and I'm not sure I would recommend that

---

Other answers already mentioned `os.walk()`, but it could be explained better. It's quite simple! Let's walk through this tree:

```
docs/
└── doc1.odt
pics/
todo.txt
```

With this code:

```
for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    print(currentpath)
```

The `currentpath` is the current folder it is looking at. This will output:

```
.
./docs
./pics
```

So it loops three times, because there are three folders: the current one, `docs`, and `pics`. In every loop, it fills the variables `folders` and `files` with all folders and files. Let's show them:

```
for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    print(currentpath, folders, files)
```

This shows us:

```
# currentpath  folders           files
.              ['pics', 'docs']  ['todo.txt']
./pics         []                []
./docs         []                ['doc1.odt']
```

So in the first line, we see that we are in folder `.`, that it contains two folders namely `pics` and `docs`, and that there is one file, namely `todo.txt`. You don't have to do anything to recurse into those folders, because as you see, it recurses automatically and just gives you the files in any subfolders. And any subfolders of that (though we don't have those in the example).

If you just want to loop through all files, the equivalent of `find -type f`, you can do this:

```
for currentpath, folders, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        print(os.path.join(currentpath, file))
```

This outputs:

```
./todo.txt
./docs/doc1.odt
```

Answer (score 20):

The `pathlib` library is really great for working with files.  You can do a recursive glob on a `Path` object like so.

```
from pathlib import Path

for elem in Path('/path/to/my/files').rglob('*.*'):
    print(elem)
```

Answer (score 10):

```
import glob
import os

root_dir = <root_dir_here>

for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/**', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename,'r') as file:
            print(file.read())
```

`**/**` is used to get all files recursively including `directory`.

`if os.path.isfile(filename)` is used to check if `filename` variable is `file` or `directory`, if it is file then we can read that file.
Here I am printing file.

Answer (score 10):

I've found the following to be the easiest

```py
from glob import glob
import os

files = [f for f in glob('rootdir/**', recursive=True) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

Using `glob('some/path/**', recursive=True)` gets all files, but also includes directory names. Adding the `if os.path.isfile(f)` condition filters this list to existing files only

Answer (score 8):

If you want a flat list of all paths under a given dir (like `find .` in the shell):

```
   files = [ 
       os.path.join(parent, name)
       for (parent, subdirs, files) in os.walk(YOUR_DIRECTORY)
       for name in files + subdirs
   ]
```

To only include full paths to files under the base dir, leave out `+ subdirs`.

Answer (score 5):

For my taste `os.walk()` is a little too complicated and verbose. You can do the accepted answer cleaner by:

```
all_files = [str(f) for f in pathlib.Path(dir_path).glob("**/*") if f.is_file()]

with open(outfile, 'wb') as fout:
    for f in all_files:
        with open(f, 'rb') as fin:
            fout.write(fin.read())
            fout.write(b'\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

use `os.path.join()` to construct your paths - It's neater:

```
import os
import sys
rootdir = sys.argv[1]
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for folder in subFolders:
        outfileName = os.path.join(root,folder,"py-outfile.txt")
        folderOut = open( outfileName, 'w' )
        print "outfileName is " + outfileName
        for file in files:
            filePath = os.path.join(root,file)
            toWrite = open( filePath).read()
            print "Writing '" + toWrite + "' to" + filePath
            folderOut.write( toWrite )
        folderOut.close()
```

Comment: It looks like this code works for folders 2 levels (or deeper) only. Still it does get me closer.

Answer (score 2):

If just the file names are not enough, it's easy to implement a [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on top of `os.scandir()`:

```
stack = ['.']
files = []
total_size = 0
while stack:
    dirname = stack.pop()
    with os.scandir(dirname) as it:
        for e in it:
            if e.is_dir(): 
                stack.append(e.path)
            else:
                size = e.stat().st_size
                files.append((e.path, size))
                total_size += size
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) have this to say:

> The scandir() function returns directory entries along with file attribute information, giving better performance for many common use cases.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run this, I get locked in an infinite loop if there are any subdirectories. It seems like there is a need to keep track of which directories have already been visited, or the loop will get stuck in re-doing them until all the computer memory is used up.

Answer (score 1):

`os.walk` does recursive walk by default. For each dir, starting from root it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)

```py
from os import walk
from os.path import splitext, join

def select_files(root, files):
    """
    simple logic here to filter out interesting files
    .py files in this example
    """

    selected_files = []

    for file in files:
        #do concatenation here to get full path 
        full_path = join(root, file)
        ext = splitext(file)[1]

        if ext == ".py":
            selected_files.append(full_path)

    return selected_files

def build_recursive_dir_tree(path):
    """
    path    -    where to begin folder scan
    """
    selected_files = []

    for root, dirs, files in walk(path):
        selected_files += select_files(root, files)

    return selected_files
```

Comment: In Python 2.6 `walk()` **do** return recursive list. I tried your code and got a list with many repeats... If you just remove lines under the comment "# recursive calls on subfolders" - it works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an (almost) Oneliner:

```
from pathlib import Path

lookuppath = '.' #use your path
filelist = [str(item) for item in Path(lookuppath).glob("**/*") if Path(item).is_file()]
```

In this case you will get a list with just the paths of all files located recursively under lookuppath.
Without str() you will get PosixPath() added to each path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not processing the output of `os.walk` correctly.

Firstly, change:

```
filePath = rootdir + '/' + file
```

to:

```
filePath = root + '/' + file
```

`rootdir` is your fixed starting directory; `root` is a directory returned by `os.walk`.

Secondly, you don't need to indent your file processing loop, as it makes no sense to run this for each subdirectory.  You'll get `root` set to each subdirectory.  You don't need to process the subdirectories by hand unless you want to do something with the directories themselves.

Comment: I have data in each sub directory, so I need to have a separate text file for the contents of each directory.

Comment: @Brock: the files part is the list of files in the current directory.  So the indentation is indeed wrong.  You are writing to `filePath = rootdir + '/' + file`, that doesn't sound right: file is from the list of current files, so you are writing to a lot of existing files?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import sys

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):

    for file in os.listdir(root):

        filePath = os.path.join(root, file)

        if os.path.isdir(filePath):
            pass

        else:
            f = open (filePath, 'r')
            # Do Stuff
```

Comment: Why would you do another listdir() and then isdir() when you already have the directory listing split into files and directories from walk()? This looks like it would be rather slow in large trees (do three syscalls instead of one: 1=walk, 2=listdir, 3=isdir, instead of just walk and loop through the 'subdirs' and 'files').

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import glob

root_dir = "C:\\Users\\Scott\\" # Don't forget trailing (last) slashes    
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.jpg', recursive=True):
     print(filename)
     # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Python [3.12](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.12.html), you can also use [`walk()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.walk) from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) which is similar to [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), but yields tuples of `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)` where `dirpath` is a [`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path). For example:

```
from pathlib import Path

for root, dirs, files in Path("cpython/Lib/concurrent").walk(on_error=print):
  print(
      root,
      "consumes",
      sum((root / file).stat().st_size for file in files),
      "bytes in",
      len(files),
      "non-directory files"
  )
  if '__pycache__' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('__pycache__')
```