# Python 2.7 How to list files in a directory AND all sub directories?

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

I am writing a script that lists number of lanes, words in text files and now I want to add looking for duplicates.

right now I am using this to list all the text files in a directory:

```
from sys import argv 
script, directory - argv
files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.txt")
```

If there are any sub-folders in the directory it will not list those files. How can I do it so that it lists all files from all sub-directories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see
[Python recursive folder read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read)

and

[Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

These are useful posts with solutions and great explanation

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html?highlight=walk#os.walk).

```
files = [f for (dir, subdirs, fs) in os.walk(directory) for f in fs if f.endswith(".txt")]
```