# Zipping a folder with os.walk

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to zip a folder and every contained subfolder and file using `os.walk()`, but I am having trouble removing the folder path to the root folder - meaning I would like to remove `D:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop` when opening up the zipfile, but instead open straight to the root folder.

I've been trying to use `os.path.basename()` and zipfile's `arcname` argument, but just can't seem to get it right:

```
def backupToZip(folder):

    import zipfile, os

    folder = os.path.abspath(folder) # make sure folder is absolute

    # Walk the entire folder tree and compress the files in each folder.  
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):

        # Add the current folder to the ZIP file.
        backupZip.write(foldername)

        # Add all the files in this folder to the ZIP file.
        for filename in filenames:
            backupZip.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename))
    backupZip.close()

backupToZip('Sample Folder')
```

Comment: Could you post what you would like the zipped archive structure to look like? Your code as you posted it is a bit confusing because it's recursive without an initial call to the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read?

Comment: @hobenkr: Sorry for any confusion - I would like the zip folder structure to be `Sample Folder\Subfolders and Files\Subfolders and Files` instead of `D:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Sample Folder\\Subfolders and Files\\Subfolders and Files`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid chdir, which impacts the whole process, you can use [relpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to get the relative path starting from your top folder.

You could use something like

```
def backupToZip(folder):

    import zipfile, os

    folder = os.path.abspath(folder) # make sure folder is absolute

    # Walk the entire folder tree and compress the files in each folder.  
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):

        if foldername == folder:
             archive_folder_name = ''
        else:
             archive_folder_name = os.path.relpath(foldername, folder)

             # Add the current folder to the ZIP file.
             backupZip.write(foldername, arcname=archive_folder_name)

        # Add all the files in this folder to the ZIP file.
        for filename in filenames:
            backupZip.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename), arcname=os.path.join(archive_folder_name, filename))
    backupZip.close()

backupToZip('Sample Folder')
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very close, just had to add in `backupZip = zipfile.ZipFile('backup.zip', 'w')`. Also, it removed the root folder being zipped, ie it went straight from zipfile to subfolders - anyway to retain the root folder?

Comment: Figured out how to retain root folder per answer below - thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `os.chdir` to change your current path
2. Make sure that the parameter of `os.walk` is relative path

*Should be careful when using `os.chdir`

---

```
import zipfile, os

def backupToZip(folder):

    cwdpath = os.getcwd() # save original path (*where you run this py file)

    saveToWhere = "tmp.zip"
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(saveToWhere, mode='w')

    folder = os.path.abspath(folder) # make sure folder is absolute
    os.chdir(folder) # change to that absolute path

    # os.walk(relative_path)
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk("./"):
        for filename in filenames:
            zf.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename))    
    zf.close()

    os.chdir(cwdpath) # back to original path
```

Comment: Thanks! - this was really close, but besides missing a `zf.write(foldername)` before `for filename in filesnames`, it also zipped the local disk for some reason I could figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Made some revisions based on user2313067's answer above and finally got what I wanted in case anyone was curious:

```
import zipfile, os

def backupToZip(folder):

    # Make sure folder is absolute.
    folder = os.path.abspath(folder) 

    backupZip = zipfile.ZipFile('backup.zip', 'w')

    backupZip.write(folder, arcname=os.path.basename(folder))


    # Walk the entire folder tree and compress the files in each folder.  
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):

        # Add the current folder to the ZIP file if not root folder
        if foldername != folder:
            backupZip.write(foldername, arcname=os.path.relpath(foldername, os.path.dirname(folder)))

        # Add all the files in this folder to the ZIP file.
        for filename in filenames:
            backupZip.write(os.path.join(foldername, filename), arcname=os.path.join(os.path.relpath(foldername, os.path.dirname(folder)), filename))
    backupZip.close()
```

Comment: Note: you should avoid `import`s inside functions. Put the at the start of your module/script.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the input - could you please help explain why this is better practice? Any other input on shortening/optimizing would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: First of all to avoid repetition. If in a module you have 3 functions that need module `os` you don't want to add `import os` three times. Moreover putting the imports at the beginning of the file shows clearly the dependencies of a program. Anybody reading it can immediately know if some 3rd party libraries are required and which ones. Finally: hiding the imports means that if the user does not have that required library installed the `ImportError` gets triggered only when the function is called, which may make debugging harder; it's better to fail as early as possible.

Comment: Also inside functions you cannot use the wildcard form: `from os import *` does not work inside a function definition but does at the module level.