# Need to read every file of directory for particular word around 172 directories,we have done for single directory

Tags: python

Here is the below code we have developed for single directory of files

```
from os import listdir

with open("/user/results.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("/user/stream"):
        with open('/user/stream/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            if 'checksum' in text:
                f.write('current word in ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('NOT ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

I want loop for all directories
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share a sample of your directory structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python recursive folder read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read)

Comment: thanks for you response actual my directory like this "/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error" dynamically app_id will come

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UNIX you can use grep:

```
grep "checksum" -R /user/stream
```

The -R flag allows for a recursive search inside the directory, following the symbolic links if there are any.

Comment: we need to use python only

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

The `glob` module allows you to work with files. In the `Unix` universe, a directory is / should be a file so it should be able to help you with your task.

More over, you don't have to install anything, `glob` comes with `python`.

Note: For the following code, you will need `python3.5` or greater

---

This should help you out.

```
import os
import glob

for path in glob.glob('/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/**', recursive=True):
    # At some point, `path` will be `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error`
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        # Check the `id` of the file
        # Do things with the file
        # If there are files inside `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error` you will be able to access them here
```

What `glob.glob` does is, it `Return a possibly-empty list of path names that match pathname`. In this case, it will match every file (including directories) in `/user/stream/`. If these files are not directories, you can do whatever you want with them.

I hope this will help you!

---

**Clarification**

Regarding your 3 point comment attempting to clarify the question, especially this part `we need to put appi dynamically in that path then we need to read all files inside that directory`

No, you do not need to do this. Please read my answer carefully and please read `glob` documentation.

> In this case, it will match every file (including directories) in /user/stream/

If you replace `/user/stream/` with `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/`, you will have access to every file in `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/`. Assuming your `app ids` are `1, 2, 3`, this means, you will have access to the following files.

```
/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_1_pvt/error
/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_2_pvt/error
/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_3_pvt/error
```

You do not have to specify the id, because you will be iterating over all files. If you do need the `id`, you can just extract it from the `path`.

If everything looks like this, `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error`, you can get the `id` by removing `/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/` and taking everything until you encounter `_`.

Comment: @ramreddy Don't forget to select this answer as the correct one if you find it useful!

Comment: thanks for response my requirement is we have app ID's by using those id's we need to go directory and read files for a word for single directory I have done  I m asking for loop directory structure is "/ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error"  please help me

Comment: You are not expressing yourself clearly. I do not understand what you are trying to do. The code I gave you gives you access to **ALL** files inside `/user/stream/`. You can check for the `id` as you iterate over. Can you try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do?

Comment: 1.we will get appids
2.directory structure is /ai2/data/prod/admin/inf/inf_<$APP>_pvt/error
3.according appid we need to put appi dynamically in that path then we need to read all files inside that directory

Comment: @ramreddy The scenario you are describing works with the provided answer.

Comment: thank you we have go through every directory acoording to appid only

Comment: @ramreddy You are not understanding the answer and you are most likely not understanding your own task. I don't know what your requirements are but `have go through every directory acoording to appid only` is not part of it, I guarantee it. Please read the question you asked and my answer again.