# Iterating over .wav files in subdirectories of parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

Cheers everybody,

I need help with something in python 3.6 exactly. So i have structure of data like this:

```
  |main directory
  |    |subdirectory's(plural)
  |    |      |.wav files
```

I'm currently working from a directory where main directory is placed so I don't need to specify paths before that. So firstly I wanna iterate over my main directory and find all subdirectorys. Then in each of them I wanna find the .wav files, and when done with processing them I wanna go to next subdirectory and so on until all of them are opened, and all .wav files are processed. Exactly what I wanna do with those .wav files is input them in my program, process them so i can convert them to numpy arrays, and then I convert that numpy array into some other object (working with tensorflow to be exact, and wanna convert to TF object). I wrote about the whole process if anybody has any fast advices on doing that too so why not.
I tried doing it with for loops like:

```
for subdirectorys in open(data_path, "r"):
    for files in subdirectorys:
        #doing some processing stuff with the file
```

The problem is that it always raises error 13, Permission denied showing on that data_path I gave him but when I go to properties there it seems okay and all permissions are fine.
I tried some other ways like with os.open or i replaced for loop with:

```
with open(data_path, "r") as data:
```

and it always raises permission denied error. 
os.walk works in some way but it's not what I need, and when i tried to modify it id didn't give errors but it also didnt do anything.
Just to say I'm not any pro programmer in python so I may be missing an obvious thing but ehh, I'm here to ask and learn. I also saw a lot of similiar questions but they mainly focus on .txt files and not specificaly in my case so I need to ask it here.
Anyway thanks for help in advance.

Comment: [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) ? Since you are using Python 3.4+, you might want to use [`pathlib.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Comment: @g_m is correct, that would be the preferred way. note that the reason you're getting the permission denied error is because you're not allowed to open a directory for reading, like you can a file (in python, this is allowed by some OSs and programming languages). a quick google shows python doesn't even expose the underlying unix opendir function like some other scripting languages do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** If you want an example for glob (more sane), here it is:

```
from pathlib import Path

# The pattern "**" means all subdirectories recursively,
# with "*.wav" meaning all files with any name ending in ".wav".
for file in Path(data_path).glob("**/*.wav"):
    if not file.is_file():  # Skip directories
        continue

    with open(file, "w") as f:
        # do stuff
```

For more info see [`Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) on the documentation. Glob patterns are a useful thing to know.

**Previous answer:**

Try using either glob or `os.walk()`. Here is an example for `os.walk()`.

```
from os import walk, path

# Recursively walk the directory data_path
for root, _, files in walk(data_path):
    # files is a list of files in the current root, so iterate them
    for file in files:
        # Skip the file if it is not *.wav
        if not file.endswith(".wav"):
            continue

        # os.path.join() will create the path for the file
        file = path.join(root, files)
        # Do what you need with the file
        # You can also use block context to open the files like this
        with open(file, "w") as f:  # "w" means permission to write. If reading, use "r"
             # Do stuff
```

Note that you may be confused about what `open()` does. It opens a file for reading, writing, and appending. Directories are not files, and therefore cannot be opened.

I suggest that you Google for documentation and do more reading about the functions used. The documentation will help more than I can.

Another good answer explaining in more detail [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read).

Comment: I was just reading through the `pathlib` docs and noticed [`Path.rglob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob) too. It only saves a couple characters but I just wanted to leave it here for the future.

Comment: Thank you sir for help. I haven't tried other people's code because this one does what I need. Although maybe I will need to modify other examples later but this one currently fits the best for my use. I think the reason I was getting permission denied error was not that my directories or files weren't accessible than my wrong code, like I was trying to open a directory as you said isn't possible and is used only for opening files.

Comment: @deva56 Obviously I'm biased, but this solution is far more elegant than others (some other answers were even deleted). This is the "correct" way of doing such a thing. The one other answer that is still up has some flaws. It's not very readable and doesn't seem to follow "The Zen of Python", it also isn't performant.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import os

main = '/main_wavs'
wavs = [w for w in glob.glob(os.path.join(main, '*/*.wav')) if os.path.isfile(w)]
```

In terms of permissions on a path A/B/C... A, B and C must all be accessible.  For files that means read permission.  For directories, it means read and execute permissions (listing contents).

Comment: There is no reason to use list comprehension for this. Making a list of the files only means that OP has to iterate over a list twice, once to create it, and again to use the files.