# How to find and then open file with Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

I want to find a file and open it!
Right now I have some problems!
Basically, I don't know how to find the file, I know how to find a file in the same directory but not globally on the computer! Can anyone help me?
Hier is my code

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".txt"):
    for filename in files:
        os.startfile(filename)
```

Comment: A good place to start might be walking from the root of the file system instead of wherever this is run from. What os are you on?

Answer (score 1):

[Reading the fine documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) would be a good place to start.
"Globally on the computer" means `/` slash.
Start there, or perhaps in your home directory.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            os.startfile(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try my answer at:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read/55193831#55193831
```

code:

```
import glob
import os

root_dir = <root_dir_here>

for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/**', recursive=True):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        with open(filename,'r') as file:
            print(file.read())
```