# how can I resolve a folders walking with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure

I'm trying to resolve this problem:

Have a tree structure like this:

```
── geny16
│   ├── gen26xgeny16
│   │   ├── sustrato270
│   │   │   ├── sustrato270_data01.dat
│   │   │   ├── sustrato270_data02.dat
│   │   │   └── sustrato270_data03.dat
│   │   ├── sustrato90
│   │   │   ├── sustrato90_data01.dat
│   │   │   ├── sustrato90_data02.dat
│   │   │   └── sustrato90_data03.dat
│   │   ├── tentata0
│   │   │   ├── tentata0_data01.dat
│   │   │   ├── tentata0_data02.dat
│   │   │   └── tentata0_data03.dat
│   │   └── tenteta90
│   │   │   ├── tentata90_data01.dat
│   │   │   ├── tentata90_data02.dat
│   │   │   └── tentata90_data03.dat
│   └── gen40xgeny16
│       ├── sustrato270
│       ├── sustrato90
│       ├── tenteta0
│       └── tenteta90
└── geny9
    ├── gen16xgeny9
    │   ├── sustrato270
    ├── sustrato90
    │   ├── tenteta0
    │   └── tenteta90
    ├── gen26xgeny9
    │   ├── sustrato270
    │   ├── sustrato90
    │   ├── tenteta0
    │   └── tenteta90
    └── gen40xgen9y
        ├── sustrato270
        ├── sustrato90
        ├── tenteta0
        └── tenteta90
```

in each deeper folder there are some .dat files that I will manipulate and plot with matplotlib. When I use a python script inside the deeper folder, my work is done: read each data file, normalize a column, superspose and plot data; but as it's the same task for each deep folder, I would like to leave the script in the root folder and that goes through the subfolders to manipulate and plot data.

I can list the name of each element in the tree with this code:

```
rootDir = '.'

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Directorio encontrado: %s' % subdirList)
    for fname in fileList:
        print('\t%s' % fname)
```

But it's only a list of names, how can I use this list to navigate and execute my script to manipulate and plot data in each deeper folders?

Thanks in advance for your comments and suggestions.

Gustavo.

Comment: can u share how r u manuplating each dat file

Comment: I want to get the full path of a file and process it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python recursive folder read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib`

```py
from pathlib import Path

root_dir = '.' # __file__
d = Path(root_dir).glob('*/*/*/*.dat') #*==any folder/file

for i in d:
    print(i.name, i.parent, i.parts[-2])
    print(i.resolve())
    print(i.stem)

    # code to manipulate these files here
    # e.g read, visualise and store data
```

See what you get. You can the do whatever you wish with the files