# Script to print files in current directory recursively

Tags: python, shell

I need to write a script that would print all files recursively in the current working directory that are bigger than 100kb.

I have experience in scripting in python and shell script and I know how to do it in a non-recursive function but I'm having trouble writing it recursively.
I would be happy if anyone here could help with examples

So far I have searched the internet for answers and tried to write some scripts in python with the use of the command `with open(dirpath) as cur_dir` but I can't figure out how to do it recursively

Comment: Could you please share your approach? I know you are new in this community, but we encourage people to try the first approach, to investigate and to put some effort in their first attempts. Please share what you have tried so far, I know a lot of people will be happy to help you :D.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, I tried to search over the internet and wrote scripts that were basically really bad so that's why I'm not uploading any example..

Comment: As you have tagged `bash` you can use `find . -type f -size +100KB`

Comment: You may use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212643/python-recursive-folder-read as a reference. Add a file check and the size check and you'll get the way to recursively trace files >= 100Kb

Comment: Hi tnx for the comments, I encounter that question but I don't see any recursion there, is it possible that recursion includes the use of a for or while loop?