# Function to display files isn't working - Python

Tags: python

For my class I have to write code that will receive a pathname and then display the file contents if its a file or display each file and its contents if a directory is the pathname.

I wrote the following code, which works fine when I test it with my own local directory. But when I run the checks on my class portal it returns an error "No such file or directory".

Can anyone help me see what's wrong with my code?

```
import os

def openFyle(filename):
    openFile = open(filename)
    return openFile.read()

def displayFiles(filename):
    if os.path.isdir(filename):
        os.chdir(filename)
        print("Directory name:", os.getcwd())
        dirLyst = os.listdir(filename)
        for file in dirLyst:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                return print("File name:", file, openFyle(file))
            elif os.path.exists(file) and os.path.isdir(file):
                    os.chdir(file)
                    displayFiles(os.getcwd())
    else:
        print("File name:", filename, openFyle(filename))
        
def main():
    #while True:
    filename = input("Enter a pathname: ")
    displayFiles(filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The directory you are passing it does not exist on the class portal.

Comment: Use `os.getcwd()` to print out the directory that the script will be running in and then use a relative path from that location, or else find the absolute path of the directory you are trying to access and pass in that.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not passing it any directory (am I?). I think the portal runs automated tests that pass it path names.

Comment: `return` stops your loop, but why are you using `os.getcwd()` in your recursion?

Comment: `filename = input("Enter a pathname: ")` this is reading in a path name

Comment: It isn't even clear if this is a bug in the code itself, or just you misreading the directions/requirements. If you ask on SO, make sure it's clear

Comment: @OneCricketeer To move down to subdirectory and repeat process.

Comment: There are multiple branches and only one returns. Why does the outer else not return? - There is discrepancy between the branches in the displayFiles method

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ask on Substack because I always get almost immediate feedback! I will look into relative path thing you mentioned.

Comment: @AK47 One return for each element that is a file in the list of elements in the directory.

Comment: As soon as return is called, it will stop processing the other files - you might want to remove that? The problem with automated tests is that you need to read the requirement really carefully - are they asking for multiple files to be output to the screen?

Comment: Well, you don't need `os.chdir`, so `os.getcwd()` is also not needed within the function itself. You should be using `displayFiles(file)` to enter a subdirectory. You might also want to look at the `os.walk` or `glob` functions

Comment: Have you tested your code locally with a directory that has multiple files?

Comment: @AK47 Yes, sorry, I have fiddled with the code so much the last two hours that I forget what I changed for class portal vs what I had for my Jupyter notebook. You're right that return wasn't needed. I added it for a test in class portal. It works fine on my local files and directories.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for pointing out unnecessary bits. I'm not very familiar with os module and will look into what you mentioned more. I had to read through it earlier to get the isfile method.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193831/4889267

Comment: @AK47 Wow, thanks! I have never heard of glob so I don't think I'm expected to solve the problem with this. (We just had case study with os module in this chapter.) But this is  a cool way to solve the problem and I'll make a note of it for future use.

Comment: @OneCricketeer when I remove os.chdir(file) and just have displayFile(file) in the body of the elif, my function returns an error when hits a subdirectory. But with those lines it behaves the way I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `os` module:

```
import os

def print_all_file_contents(directory):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            print(open(os.path.join(root, file)).read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print_all_file_contents(input("Enter a directory:"))
```

Comment: Awesome how concise this is! It works on my local files, but I'll need to tinker with it to understand the syntax better and test it on my class portal tomorrow.

Comment: Updated it slightly. Take the latest version

Comment: @AfterVirtue Tinker what? Just read the documentation. Python is very well-documented.

Comment: @user202729 For instance doing stuff like this just helps me understand what the syntax is doing  (sorry, don't know how to make formatting work in comments, but you may get the gist):
`def display_files(path): for x, y, z in os.walk(path):     print("This is root?", x)
        print("This is dir?", y)print("These are files?", z)
        for a in z:
            print("This is file", a, "in", z)
            print(open(x + "/" + a).read())`

Comment: Note that this won't print the contents if the supplied path is a file rather than a directory.

Answer (score 0):

What I would guess is, one of the tests they're using on your function is to send an invalid path. In your function, you only cover two cases: either its a path or its a file and you print out the file name with its contents. What if you cant find that file? That `else` should be an `elif` that does the `os.path.isfile`, and then an `else` in case its an invalid path.

This should fix it.

```
def displayFiles(filename):
    if os.path.isdir(filename):
        os.chdir(filename)
        print("Directory name:", os.getcwd())
        dirLyst = os.listdir(filename)
        for file in dirLyst:
            if os.path.isfile(file):
                return print("File name:", file, openFyle(file))
            elif os.path.exists(file) and os.path.isdir(file):
                    os.chdir(file)
                    displayFiles(os.getcwd())
    elif os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("File name:", filename, openFyle(filename))
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: You shouldn't really be taking guesses -- does this code work with multiple files in a directory?

Comment: I still receive same error. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

> . I think the portal runs automated tests that pass it path names.

Sure, but that doesn't prevent it from giving you invalid input data, such as non-str or Path-like objects or non existing locations

Also, rather than using chdir, create the absolute path as you go using `path.join`

```
def displayFiles(filename):
    if filename and os.path.exists(filename):
        if os.path.isdir(filename):
            print("Directory name:", filename)
            for file in os.listdir(filename):
                child = os.path.join(filename,file) 
                displayFiles(child)
        else:
            print("File name:", filename, openFyle(filename))
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost any time you're working with file system paths in Python, I recommend [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), because [it's awesome](https://treyhunner.com/2018/12/why-you-should-be-using-pathlib/). It doesn't make a huge difference this this case, but getting used to using it will make things much easier when you need to, say, join multiple paths together.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def display_file(path):
    print(f'File: {path}\n')
    print(path.read_text())
    print('\n\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = Path(input('Enter a pathname: '))

    if path.is_dir():
        for item in path.iterdir():
            # This avoids attempting to print hidden files, which may exist
            # depending on the OS / filesystem.
            if item.is_file() and not item.name.startswith('.'):
                display_file(item)

    elif path.is_file():
        display_file(path)
```

The code only tries to print contents if the path is in fact a file or a directory; it displays nothing if passed an invalid or nonexistant path.