# How to get a list of files in nested directories from a given path, irrespective of file extension?

Tags: python

I get that I can use `glob.glob("./**/*")` but this seems to include the directory names in the result set. If I try `glob.glob("./**/*.*")` instead, it excludes files that do not have any file extensions. How do I get a result set that gives all the files irrespective of file extension?

Comment: You know that filenames don't have to be of the form xxx.yyy and that folder names can be of the form xxx.yyy, yes?

Comment: @jarmod I hadn't considered that. In that case, ```glob.glob("./**/*.*")``` would pick up those results as well

Comment: Or [Python recursive folder read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2212643/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
folderpath = ''
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(folderpath):
    for fname in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
        print(dirname)
        print(fname)
        print(full_path)
```